# UnsatisfiedLinkException when running JavaCpp example (LegacyLibrary)

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, javacpp

I'm trying to build and run the [LegacyLibrary Example](http://code.google.com/p/javacpp/#Accessing_Native_APIs) of JavaCpp with Visual Studio 2008 on Windows XP Professional (x86) using JDK 1.7.0 and JavaCpp 0.3 (bin), and I get the following output. The error is on the last command, `java -cp javacpp.jar LegacyLibrary`.

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Brian\My Documents\Projects\Copy of Hello_JNI\src\graf
\JavaCpp>dir
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 9099-0685

 Directory of C:\Documents and Settings\Brian\My Documents\Projects\Copy of Hell
o_JNI\src\graf\JavaCpp

22/01/2013  10:19 AM    <DIR>          .
22/01/2013  10:19 AM    <DIR>          ..
04/11/2012  09:00 PM           109,991 javacpp.jar
22/01/2013  10:18 AM               297 LegacyLibrary.h
22/01/2013  10:19 AM             1,058 LegacyLibrary.java
               3 File(s)        111,346 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  362,833,334,272 bytes free

C:\Documents and Settings\Brian\My Documents\Projects\Copy of Hello_JNI\src\graf
\JavaCpp>javac -cp javacpp.jar LegacyLibrary.java

C:\Documents and Settings\Brian\My Documents\Projects\Copy of Hello_JNI\src\graf
\JavaCpp>java -jar javacpp.jar LegacyLibrary
Generating source file: C:\Documents and Settings\Brian\My Documents\Projects\Co
py of Hello_JNI\src\graf\JavaCpp\jniLegacyLibrary.cpp
Building library file: C:\Documents and Settings\Brian\My Documents\Projects\Cop
y of Hello_JNI\src\graf\JavaCpp\windows-x86\jniLegacyLibrary.dll
cl /IC:\jdk1.7.0\include /IC:\jdk1.7.0\include\win32 "C:\Documents and Settings\
Brian\My Documents\Projects\Copy of Hello_JNI\src\graf\JavaCpp\jniLegacyLibrary.
cpp" /W3 /Oi /O2 /EHsc /Gy /GL /MD /LD /link "/OUT:C:\Documents and Settings\Bri
an\My Documents\Projects\Copy of Hello_JNI\src\graf\JavaCpp\windows-x86\jniLegac
yLibrary.dll" /LIBPATH:C:\jdk1.7.0\lib /LIBPATH:C:\jdk1.7.0\jre\bin\server jvm.l
ib
Microsoft (R) 32-bit C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 15.00.21022.08 for 80x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

jniLegacyLibrary.cpp
C:\Documents and Settings\Brian\My Documents\Projects\Copy of Hello_JNI\src\graf
\JavaCpp\jniLegacyLibrary.cpp(113) : warning C4996: 'strcpy': This function or v
ariable may be unsafe. Consider using strcpy_s instead. To disable deprecation,
use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
        c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\INCLUDE\string.h(74) : s
ee declaration of 'strcpy'
C:\Documents and Settings\Brian\My Documents\Projects\Copy of Hello_JNI\src\graf
\JavaCpp\jniLegacyLibrary.cpp(115) : warning C4996: 'strncpy': This function or
variable may be unsafe. Consider using strncpy_s instead. To disable deprecation
, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
        c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\INCLUDE\string.h(157) :
see declaration of 'strncpy'
C:\Documents and Settings\Brian\My Documents\Projects\Copy of Hello_JNI\src\graf
\JavaCpp\jniLegacyLibrary.cpp(185) : warning C4996: 'strdup': The POSIX name for
 this item is deprecated. Instead, use the ISO C++ conformant name: _strdup. See
 online help for details.
        c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\INCLUDE\string.h(207) :
see declaration of 'strdup'
C:\Documents and Settings\Brian\My Documents\Projects\Copy of Hello_JNI\src\graf
\JavaCpp\jniLegacyLibrary.cpp(340) : warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion from
 'jlong' to 'size_t', possible loss of data
C:\Documents and Settings\Brian\My Documents\Projects\Copy of Hello_JNI\src\graf
\JavaCpp\jniLegacyLibrary.cpp(354) : warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion from
 'jlong' to 'size_t', possible loss of data
C:\Documents and Settings\Brian\My Documents\Projects\Copy of Hello_JNI\src\graf
\JavaCpp\jniLegacyLibrary.cpp(370) : warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion from
 'jlong' to 'size_t', possible loss of data
C:\Documents and Settings\Brian\My Documents\Projects\Copy of Hello_JNI\src\graf
\JavaCpp\jniLegacyLibrary.cpp(385) : warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion from
 'jlong' to 'size_t', possible loss of data
C:\Documents and Settings\Brian\My Documents\Projects\Copy of Hello_JNI\src\graf
\JavaCpp\jniLegacyLibrary.cpp(393) : warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion from
 'jlong' to 'size_t', possible loss of data
C:\Documents and Settings\Brian\My Documents\Projects\Copy of Hello_JNI\src\graf
\JavaCpp\jniLegacyLibrary.cpp(956) : warning C4800: 'jboolean' : forcing value t
o bool 'true' or 'false' (performance warning)
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 9.00.21022.08
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

/out:jniLegacyLibrary.dll
/ltcg
/dll
/implib:jniLegacyLibrary.lib
"/OUT:C:\Documents and Settings\Brian\My Documents\Projects\Copy of Hello_JNI\sr
c\graf\JavaCpp\windows-x86\jniLegacyLibrary.dll"
/LIBPATH:C:\jdk1.7.0\lib
/LIBPATH:C:\jdk1.7.0\jre\bin\server
jvm.lib
jniLegacyLibrary.obj
   Creating library jniLegacyLibrary.lib and object jniLegacyLibrary.exp
Generating code
Finished generating code

C:\Documents and Settings\Brian\My Documents\Projects\Copy of Hello_JNI\src\graf
\JavaCpp>java -cp javacpp.jar LegacyLibrary
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Documents and Sett
ings\Brian\Local Settings\Temp\javacpp92803190928456\jniLegacyLibrary.dll: Can't
 find dependent libraries
        at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1928)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1825)
        at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:792)
        at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1059)
        at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.loadLibrary(Loader.java:422)
        at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:372)
        at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:319)
        at LegacyLibrary$LegacyClass.<clinit>(LegacyLibrary.java:8)
        at LegacyLibrary.main(LegacyLibrary.java:22)

C:\Documents and Settings\Brian\My Documents\Projects\Copy of Hello_JNI\src\graf
\JavaCpp>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that Visual Studio 2005 and VS 2008 do not automatically link to internal libraries of VC++. The solution is to either bundle a manifest with the required libraries in the executable, as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235591%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), or to simply use Visual Studio 2010 or newer. I used VS 2010 and I can verify that the example now runs as expected. If you happen to try bundling the manifest, please comment for others to confirm that it's a valid fix.

Source: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/javacpp-project/kljspKIxH9M

Answer (score 0):

It seems that java cannot find the .dll file. Try to put it into the same directory from which execute the class file.

BTW, how do you load the library in java?

Comment: Java *can* find the .dll file. If I remove the .dll file, it gives a different exception ("java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jniLegacyLibrary in java.library.path" vs. "Can't
 find dependent libraries")

Comment: Sry, my fault. Is your library dynamically linked to other libraries?

Comment: You can see the exact code and commands [here](http://code.google.com/p/javacpp/#Accessing_Native_APIs).

Comment: The only other library I can think of is the JavaCpp library itself, which is explicitly included in the command line invocation, `java -cp javacpp.jar LegacyLibrary`.

Comment: Maybe you should try http://dependencywalker.com/ to check whether your jniLegacyLibrary.dll depends on a library that Java does not find.