# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jniLegacyLibrary in java.library.path

Tags: java, c++, eclipse, javacpp

I am using [javacpp](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp) to access cpp from Java.

I have tried the example provided in the documentation

cpp code:

```
#include <string>

namespace LegacyLibrary {
    class LegacyClass {
        public:
            const std::string& get_property() { return property; }
            void set_property(const std::string& property) { this->property = property; }
            std::string property;
    };
}
```

Java code:

```
import org.bytedeco.javacpp.*;
import org.bytedeco.javacpp.annotation.*;

@Platform(include="LegacyLibrary.h")
@Namespace("LegacyLibrary")
public class LegacyLibrary {
    public static class LegacyClass extends Pointer {
        static { Loader.load(); }
        public LegacyClass() { allocate(); }
        private native void allocate();

        // to call the getter and setter functions 
        public native @StdString String get_property(); public native void set_property(String property);

        // to access the member variable directly
        public native @StdString String property();     public native void property(String property);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Pointer objects allocated in Java get deallocated once they become unreachable,
        // but C++ destructors can still be called in a timely fashion with Pointer.deallocate()
        LegacyClass l = new LegacyClass();
        l.set_property("Hello World!");
        System.out.println(l.property());
    }
}
```

My Folder structure in eclipse

[image]

I am getting following error if I run LegacyLibrary.java file in Eclipse

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jniLegacyLibrary in java.library.path
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
>     at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
>       at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.loadLibrary(Loader.java:550)
>       at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:415)
>       at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:358)
>       at LegacyLibrary$LegacyClass.(LegacyLibrary.java:8)
>       at LegacyLibrary.main(LegacyLibrary.java:22)

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: You've written "I am getting following error", but where is the error?

Comment: It look like that java is not able to find the `.dll` file. Try to put it into the same directory from where your executing the class file.

Comment: @SubodhJoshi I am new to cpp. which `.dll` file whould I add?

Comment: `jniLegacyLibrary.dll` also are you using Visual Studio?

Comment: @SubodhJoshi No. I am using nodepad++ to edit the cpp code

Comment: @SubodhJoshi create a `win32 project` and add `LegacyLibrary.h` file in `Header Files` and build `jniLegacyLibrary.dll`?

Comment: @Vishnu see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14464793/unsatisfiedlinkexception-when-running-javacpp-example-legacylibrary